# Extract all/unique words from ms word in C# without third party tool

Tags: c#, ms-word, extract

I have to extract all the words from a MS word file and then store them in a table for further searching. Is there a way to read the MS Word file word by word. I know I can copy all the text and put it in a variable and on space or tab start reading it but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a former SO post where you see how to get all text from word into a variable using C#:

[How can I grab each page of text in a Word doc separately (using .NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290287/how-can-i-grab-each-page-of-text-in-a-word-doc-separately-using-net)

Afterwards, use `string.Split(" ")` to split the text into an array of words.

EDIT: Here

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split

you find some examples for splitting a text into words using regular expressions. This one

```
 Regex.Split(s, @"\W+")
```

may suit your needs.

Comment: i have tried it but there are words that are combined e.g. in a file i found out "TECH\r\nClient:" even though it is return and a new line but i dont know what else i can face? so isn't there a word by word extraction in msword?

Comment: First you need to define what you mean by a "word". Is "don't" a word? What about "tutti-fruity"? "802.11"? Or are they two words? You need to know what you want before you can write the code.